# Why does Array.prototype.some return boolean?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I feel like this gives me very little flexibility whenever I'm using this function. Usually I'm looking for the first occurrence of the element when I use this function but it just returns `true` which I find a little lacking.
The primary reason for me to use this function is to `break` the loop whenever I find the element so using `forEach` defeats the purpose because `forEach` doesn't short-circuit. `Array.prototype.filter` is the same.

Am I missing something or do I *have* to use `for` loop to get the first matched element in JavaScript?

Comment: Care to post some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns a boolean because that's what the function definition is. It tests whether *some* (or *any*) of the elements in the array satisfy a test.

You're looking for an implementation of `first`, which in ECMAScript 6 is proposed as [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Here's a polyfill (from the MDN link):

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function(predicate) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}
```

Comment: I'm aware that the definition says so. I was rather asking why. But since it's in ES6, this would be another feature I'll be looking forward to. :) Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. (Maybe someone in TC39 guys realized this too ;) )

Comment: The *why* is because that's what it does. :P There's no more profound answer.

Comment: I wanted to know the reasoning behind the definition as to whenever it was included in the language. I guess it makes sense to make it consistent with `every`.

Comment: FWIW, `any`, `some`, `every`, `first` etc. are typical *functional primitives* present in most *functional programming languages*. ECMAScript did not exactly invent these definitions. That's about as far as you'll get for an explanation I'd think.

Comment: For example, see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#g:4

Comment: Now I'm starting to see light in my stubborn head. :D